# devise-async is not working with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

I tried to configure my devise to send emails asynchronously through sidekiq, but, the jobs are queued and never really executed.. so I never get the email send.

I also tried to made it use the default queue instead of the mailer queue, still without any success.

Versions of the gems:

```
sidekiq 2.3.0
devise 2.1.2
devise-async 0.3.1
```

`/sidekiq/` info:

```
Sidekiq is idle
Processed: 0
Failed: 0
Busy Workers: 0
Scheduled: 0
Retries Pending: 0
Queue Backlog: 5
```

I still trying to made it work here, whithou success. Starting to believe that's a bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fire up your Sidekiq workers?

Comment: So you did a "sidekiqctl start" from the command line? Did you verify the workers actually continued to run?

Comment: bug in sidekiq https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I didn't have the `hostname` command avaliable in my machine.
I filed a [bug](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/393) in sidekiq repo.

thanks