# Background mailing through sidekiq and devise-async, queue fills up but mails aren't processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, sidekiq

I'm currently building a rails platform and I've used devise for authentication and now want to move the default devise emails into a background process using sidekiq. I'm using devise-async for this and have done the following:

Added the devise_async.rb file:

```
#config/initializers/devise_async.rb
Devise::Async.backend = :sidekiq
```

Added the async command to the devise model:

```
#user.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :async #etc.
```

The versions of the gems are the following:

```
Devise 2.1.2
Devise-async 0.4.0
Sidekiq 2.5.3
```

The issue that I'm having is that the emails are passed in the sidekiq queue but the workers never execute sending the emails. I've also looked at [devise async not working with sidekiq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361077/devise-async-is-not-working-with-sidekiq) and he seemed to have the same problem. But I don't think I have an issue with the hostname command.

Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: It might be dumb to ask, but did you have a separate worker process running via `bundle exec sidekiq -C config.yaml` or something similar?

Comment: It's actually not dumb to ask, since I think stuff like that happens all the time. I actually started up redis using `redis-server` and then sidekiq using `bundle exec sidekiq`. The thing is that I know sidekiq is working since I'm also sending mails in a background process for invites, which is separate from devise.

Comment: Try `bundle exec sidekiq -q mailer`  I think devise-async use mailer queue not default.

Comment: Thank you very much :) It actually resolved the issue. I guess sidekiq  by default only serves its `default` queue, so you have to tell sidekiq to use the `mailer` queue. I'll be sure to pass it on to the devise-async module so that they can include it in their documentation!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is rather simple. You just need to tell sidekiq to use the `mailer` queue, by starting sidekiq with `bundle exec sidekiq -q mailer`. That way the mailer queue will be processed, without the option sidekiq will simply rely on the `default` queue.

Comment: To do both you can just use `bundle exec sidekiq -q mailer -q default` Note this also prioritizes the mailer queue over the default queue.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019, since **device-async** is not up to date and If you have your ActiveJob and sidekiq set-up is done [documentation here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).The most simple solution is to override you device **send_devise_notification** instance methods involved with the transactions mails like shown [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Authenticatable#send_devise_notification-instance_method)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # whatever association you have here
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable
  after_commit :send_pending_devise_notifications
  # whatever methods you have here

 protected
  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    if new_record? || changed?
      pending_devise_notifications << [notification, args]
    else
      render_and_send_devise_message(notification, *args)
    end
  end

  private

  def send_pending_devise_notifications
    pending_devise_notifications.each do |notification, args|
      render_and_send_devise_message(notification, *args)
    end

    pending_devise_notifications.clear
  end

  def pending_devise_notifications
    @pending_devise_notifications ||= []
  end

  def render_and_send_devise_message(notification, *args)
    message = devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args)

    # Deliver later with Active Job's `deliver_later`
    if message.respond_to?(:deliver_later)
      message.deliver_later
    # Remove once we move to Rails 4.2+ only, as `deliver` is deprecated.
    elsif message.respond_to?(:deliver_now)
      message.deliver_now
    else
      message.deliver
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported by Devise
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#activejob-integration

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise ...

  # Override devise: send emails in the background
  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end

end
```